Fonts How to Control "Selection Height"
I've recently updated from Source Sans Pro to Source Sans 3 and i noticed a difference in the font size height. I can see this when i select the text.

a. Is this "OK" / out of my control and all in the font?
b. Is there anyway to control that height on top and bottom so its closer as before upgrading?
For what its worth i tried all known css properties like line-height and am using the variable font.

Why line-height didn't work? Please create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. If not, I don't think there's any other way to control line-height, or so.

I figured it out line-height does work but only when bigger than the font itself (or at a certain size it mins out)
